# My div is showing all the time, instead of loading after click event?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

for some reason my `forsaledialog` **div** is loading with the page and not waiting for jQuery to show it. It works fine in jsFiddle though!

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/YDdqP/269/

```
<div id="forsalejoepopupbutton" >
<span>For Sale</span>
</div>
<div id="forsaledialog" title="For Sale">
  this div is not hiding when the page loads!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  i really want a php file here but since it always loads i cant include! what is going on??
</div>
    $(function () {
    $("#forsaledialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 2000
        }
    });
    $("#forsalejoepopupbutton").click(function () {
        $("#forsaledialog").dialog("open");
    });
});


EDIT: THIS IS WHAT FIXED IT:
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$(window).load(function() {`

> The window load event executes a bit later when the complete page is
>   fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images. Therefore
>   functions which concern images or other page contents should be placed
>   in the load event for the window or the content tag itself.

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $("#forsaledialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "explode",
            duration: 2000
        }
    });
    $("#forsalebutton").click(function () {
        $("#forsaledialog").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

---

Updated after OP's comment

You have not included `jQuery ui` library in that page.

Comment: Interestingly this code works on another page of the site, due to the size, is it possible that something else is triggering a div to always load on the index page and pages that spawn from the index page as a different "view"?

Comment: @Petro i 'm trying to figure out problem .

Comment: If you could update your answer for future people and remove my domain name that would be awesome. Again, thank you so much! I was running into this all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good possibility I'm missing something, but why don't you style it as `display:none` or `display:hidden` and then change the display property using JavaScript once you load what you want.

Use

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'block';
```

inside of a function which you call in an `onclick` or `onpageload` or any other kind of event that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use css "display:none;" to hide the div

and

```
$("#forsalejoepopupbutton").click(function () {
        $("#forsaledialog").style.display="block";
    });
```

in order to show it again